# Butane/propane fuel for camping in Northern Calgary

Tags: canada, camping, calgary

Where in Northern Calgary could I get a fuel canister (screw-on)?

Answer (score 2):

[Canadain Tire](http://www.canadiantire.ca/) is one retailer who would sell such an item.  They have multiple locations in Northern Calgary.